# Search results with persistent result checkboxes

Tags: checkbox, google-sheets

I'm working on a sheet that will help my team track permits in cities across the United States. There are 4 projects that each have specific needs. My idea was to create a drop-down to select the state and a vlookup to search the city under the state. I want my team to be able to select their checkbox and have the check status linked to the searched city. IE we should be able to select the box when we know a permit is needed and lookup the city again to know we have needed it before. Any ideas? Please see the attached sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bka6k582_cLCCMU1MToiWILPfOIBS9KjGtxaDqRgPl4/edit#gid=0

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bka6k582_cLCCMU1MToiWILPfOIBS9KjGtxaDqRgPl4/edit?usp=sharing                                      Sorry forgot shareable link.

Comment: unclear what you want. if you want to perform search1 then play with those checkboxes then do search2 play again with those checkboxes then return to search1 and checkboxes would shift as you left them before you did search2 ... then you need to store those checkboxes via script and only then you can call them up with a formula - if thats what you want

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. "Any ideas?" Would you outline the search/research that you've already done - we wouldn't want to duplicate that.

Comment: Yes I would like to search 1 value, mark the corresponding check boxes true. Search another value, mark those corresponding check boxes true. Then if I return to search 1 the check boxes I marked reflect the original selection. I think I have a solution that requires more work however I need a vlookup that will return 5 rows based on a value in column 1. Were you able to click on the sheet?

Comment: My thought was correct, I can add check box columns to the master sheet and have them appear in the search sheet however they appear as a true false value. I would like them to appear as check boxes. Any Ideas?